# In this case, is it possible to fold Applicative <*> to avoid repetition?

Tags: haskell

In the following code

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Applicative

type Code = String

toSth :: Read a => State [Code] a
toSth = state $ \(c:cs) -> ((read c), cs)

codes = ["12", "True", ""]

data Tick = Tick {n :: Int, bid :: Bool} deriving (Show)

res = runState (pure Tick <*> toSth <*> toSth) codes

main = print res
```

I get the correct results

```
(Tick {n = 12, bid = True},[""])
```

But my problem is with the repetition of

```
pure Tick <*> toSth <*> toSth
```

I.e., if the record has 100 fields, then I have to write `<*> toSth` 100 times, which does not look Haskell.

Is there a way to `foldl` on `<*>`? I know the standard `foldl :: Foldable t => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b` won't work here, because the accumulator type changes in each iteration.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: A 100 field record does not look Haskell. If your data types are well-expressed, your terms will be too.  It's okay to use a function twice (that's pretty much the point of it)

Comment: The problem is that the list you need isn't homogenous. `pure Tick` has one type; `pure Tick <*> toSth` has another, and `pure Tick <*> toSth <*> toSth` has a third. You get the same problem if you wanted to apply `Tick` to the "list" of arguments `[12, True]`.

Comment: The only solutions I can see require either some nontrivial typeclass machinery, or Template Haskell. Both will be probably longer than writing `<*> toSth` 100 times.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done with some advanced [generics](https://wiki.haskell.org/Generics) libraries, like [generics-sop](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop).

Generics libraries translate datatypes from and to some kind of "uniform" representation. The libraries also provide functions to create or modify such representation. We can work over the representation and afterwards transform back into the original datatype.

```
{-# language DeriveGeneric, TypeApplications #-}

import qualified GHC.Generics
import           Generics.SOP (Generic,to,SOP(SOP),NS(Z),hsequence,hcpure)
import           Data.Proxy

data Tick = Tick {n :: Int, bid :: Bool} deriving (Show,GHC.Generics.Generic)

instance Generic Tick -- this Generic is from generics-sop 

res :: (Tick, [Code])
res = 
  let tickAction :: State [Code] Tick
      tickAction = to . SOP . Z <$> hsequence (hcpure (Proxy @Read) toSth)
   in runState tickAction codes
```

[`hcpure`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop-0.4.0.1/docs/Generics-SOP.html#v:hcpure) creates an [n-ary product](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop-0.4.0.1/docs/Generics-SOP.html#t:NP) out of an effectful function (here `toSth`) that knows how to create every member of the product. We have to pass a `Proxy` with the constraint to convince the compiler. The result is a product where each component is wrapped in `State`.

[`hsequence`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop-0.4.0.1/docs/Generics-SOP.html#t:HSequence) is like [`sequenceA`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:sequenceA) but for n-ary products having different types for each component. The result is similar: the `Applicative` is "pulled outwards".

[`SOP`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop-0.4.0.1/docs/Generics-SOP.html#t:SOP) and [`Z`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop-0.4.0.1/docs/Generics-SOP.html#t:NS) are constructors that wrap the product and let us call [`to`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop-0.4.0.1/docs/Generics-SOP.html#v:to) to get a value of the original `Tick` type.

`res` could be given this more general signature to work over any single-constructor record that is an instance of `Generics.SOP.Generic`:

```
{-# language DataKinds #-}

res :: (Generic r, Generics.SOP.Code r ~ '[ xs ], Generics.SOP.All Read xs) => (r,[Code])
res = 
  let tickAction = to . SOP . Z <$> hsequence (hcpure (Proxy @Read) toSth)
   in runState tickAction codes
```